# Converting a .tiff image to Polyline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, convert, line

I have imported a .tiff image of water pipelines(blue, red, purple), into ArcMap. I want to convert just the water lines into polyline vectors for measuring. Will Raster to Polyline work for this, or is there more I need to do?

Is there some sort of code to have ArcGIS recognize the colors and lines?